# My Kafka consumer retry for 10 times abnormally, and stop its retrying by simply adding a MDC log?

Tags: exception, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, mdc

I have a Kafka Listener, I send a single Kafka message to the topic, and my listener receive 10 times (the second one is after the first one complete its handling function, the third one is after the second one finish.. and so on.)

My consumer function be like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "xxx", groupId = "xxx")
public void onMessageUser(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Acknowledgment ack) {
    //some code
    //xxxx
    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

My Kafka configuration:

```
spring.kafka.producer.retries=5
spring.kafka.producer.acks=1
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=50
spring.kafka.consumer.poll-timeout=5000
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=MANUAL
```

I add a MDC(Mapped Diagnostic Context) log, and then the consumer become right!! It stop its retrying 10 times. Just receive one time, and process one time.

```
org.slf4j.MDC.put("requestId", xxx);
```

Where is the magic????

---

Update:
Great thanks to helpful suggestions from @Artem Bilan and @Gary Russell.
I have found the cause. Here is the error code in "some code" fragment:

```
Map<String,Object> prop = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();   
prop.put(CommonConstants.Request.REQUEST_ID,MDC.get(CommonConstants.Request.REQUEST_ID));
```

The “MDC.get(CommonConstants.Request.REQUEST_ID)” is null value, so it cause null pointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null    
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)     
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
```

And since I do not have a try catch block with the issue code, this exception does not print in my error log, so I fail to find that error for a long time. (I have a general Spring Web exception handler in the project, but the Kafka message does not go through my Spring Web exception handler)

The exception cause Kafka's default retry policy for retry additional 9 times.

Comment: Any chances to see a simple project from you where we can reproduce the problem on our side and debug it?

Comment: @ArtemBilan Sure. I have shared the entire code (excluding useless business code) in this document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/186pSivJEMUq-S4PLfbbISq5NeniTA3lwdaDRhoUnZtM/edit?usp=sharing  I have made my best to provide as many details as possible. If you need more detail, I will send you what you want to know.

Comment: Well, would you mind to your code via https://github.com/ repository? So, we can fork it and run locally. Not sure, though, that really need so much business-specific props.

Comment: Perhaps your `some code` is throwing an exception because the MDC `requestId` is not present? This would cause the default behavior of 9 retries with zero delay between each. You don't show your log config, but I assume the pattern requires the MDC to be present.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have post more details here:https://docs.google.com/document/d/16mUgy9jcZcN11M8gmVOFnUE7FTIPyrBe4ZG8uUfZLSM/edit?usp=sharing  The code for GitHub repository view, I will try it but not sure, because it involves many config from inner system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your `some code` is throwing an exception because the MDC `requestId` is not present.

This would cause the default behavior of 9 retries with zero delay between each.

You don't show your log config, but I assume the pattern requires the MDC to be present.

Comment: Thanks！ I have checked my logback config file, the log pattern is : 
<property name="LOG_PATTERN" value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}|%X{Request-Id}|%X{User-Id}|%msg%n"/> 
As you mentioned, it does have a Request-Id field. My question is, what does it means:" the default behavior of 9 retries", which kafka configuration param define this retry times? Or the default retry times from Kafka? Any document link for this retry behavior? 
Thanks.

Comment: When requestId is null, what exception will Logback throw ?  I think it will tolerant the null value? Either print a null value or ignore printing that field.

Comment: I have post the "some code" here for more detail: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16mUgy9jcZcN11M8gmVOFnUE7FTIPyrBe4ZG8uUfZLSM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `>which kafka configuration param define this retry times?` See the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh I don't know LogBack's behavior when MDC is missing but the log should show the exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to find that logback exception log. That log may complete this whole investigation.

Comment: Still a little bit confused about the log exception. As I check the logback document about mdc output here:https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#mdc  It says:"If the value is null, then the default value specified after the :- operator is output. If no default value is specified then the empty string is output."  So it seems a null value will not cause exception.

Comment: As I said, I don’t know log back internals, but there is a difference between an MDC that exists, but has a null value, and one that does not exist. Edit the question to show the thrown exception.

Comment: I have updated the question description, thanks for your help sir.